# Save result of each iteration python

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to use QPX Express. I want to save airports origin and destination of each loop results. When I send JSon request (Origin : ORY / Designation : LAX / Solution 2) I normally have 2 flights (perhaps with flight connecting).

```
multivol = data['trips']['tripOption']
origine_air = []
destination_air = []
for p in multivol : 
    print("")
    multivol1 = p['slice']
    prix = p['saleTotal']
        print prix
    for q in multivol1 : 
        multivol2 = q['segment']
        duree_trip = q['duration']
        duree_trip_h = duree_trip // 60
        print duree_trip_h
        for s in multivol2 :
            multivol3 = s['leg']
            for d in multivol3 : 
                ori = d['origin']
                dest = d['destination']
                heure_ar = d['arrivalTime']
                heure_de = d['departureTime']
                vol_entier = ori + dest
                print vol_entier
                origine_air.append(ori)
```

I tried to store result in a list.

My result :

```
EUR596.60
18
ORYLHR
LHRLAX

EUR596.60
20
ORYLHR
LHRLAX
[u'ORY', u'LHR', u'ORY', u'LHR']
[]
```

The result of the list isn't what I expected. When you can see for going from ORY to LAX there was a flight connecting at LRH (London) and in the list there was only the firsts flights (ORY to LHR) not the second part of the trip.

How can I have all of the trip in my list ?

thanks you

Robin

Comment: What part of storing something in a list are you having trouble with?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is : how can I store one flight (origin and destination) in a list ? I wish have something like this [u'ORY', u'LHR', u'LHR', u'LAX'] not [u'ORY', u'LHR', u'ORY', u'LHR']. It's difficult for me to parse QPX..

Comment: Are you able to loop through these origin and destinations e.g. `ORYLHR`,`LHRLAX`,`ABCDEF`,`HIJKLM`,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be your main concern is parsing a string a storing the tokens into a list. Perhaps this is what you need?

```
flights = ["ORYLHR","LHRLAX"]
#Given a list of the flights, parse them by breaking the strings up in half and storing each half in a list
originDest = []
for i in range(0,len(flights)):
    #This gets the first three chars
    origin = flights[i][0:3]

    #This gets the last three chars
    dest = flights[i][3:6]

    #Append
    originDest.append(origin)
    originDest.append(origin)
```

Output

```
['ORY','LHR','LHR','LAX']
```